# multiple parameter in get request in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api_doc/', schema_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # regex for swagger creation
    path(r'^request.GET.get(‘tag’)&request.GET.get(‘order_by’)', views.QuestionList.as_view()),
    # path(r'^?tag={tag}&order_by={name}', views.QuestionList.as_view()),
]
```

This is mu url.py file and i a trying to input "tag" and "order_by" in url in swagger but it's not working? i have tried above url options

In the last one "?" is not reconized by url.

Comment: The querystring is *not* part of the path. So you can not encode it there. You process it in the view with `request.GET`.

Comment: a = request.GET.get('tag')
b = request.GET.get('order_by') i have tried this in view.py but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

The [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is *not* part of the path. So you can not capture or check this in the `urlpatterns`. Your path looks like:

```
path('', views.QuestionList.as_view())
```

In your view, you can then filter the queryset accordingly:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from app.models import Question

class QuestionList(ListView):
    model = Question

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'tag' in self.request.GET:
            qs = qs.filter(tag__id=self.request.GET['tag'])
        if 'order_by' in self.request.GET:
            qs = qs.order_by(self.request.GET['order_by'])
        return qs
```

That being said, you are introducing a security vulnerability by allowing arbitrary ordening.

It furthermore might be worth to take a look at [**`django-filter`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) to do filtering based on a `QueryDict` in a more declarative way.

Comment: I am using swagger and i can't find parameter request in swagger ui with the above code

Comment: @code_freak: that makes perfect sense, since, as said, the querystring parameters are not encoded in the url, hence these can not be "specified" to the outer world. It is not very *Django*-ish to pass data through a querystring. Normally one uses the path for that.

Comment: how can i achieve this then ?